# MutualLikes count for two users is different in facebook graph api response

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I used facebook sdk to get the data from graph api using the following fields `friends.limit(100){name,id,context}` for a user A it shows B as a friend and count of mutual likes as 5. For user B friend of A the mutual likes count shows 15. Ideally the two values should be equal as they are mutual likes. Is this some bug in facebook api??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works. What you're seeing is the mutual likes count for each of the access token user's friends... I don't get why you think the values should be equal?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user.context/mutual_likes

> A list of the liked Pages that the session user and the request user have in common.